# how to do real time video/audio streaming in django

Tags: python, django, web, streaming

i want to stream the video and audio (and some real time data which i will get from precessing every fram) from surveillance camera into a django website ... i found this code that help me send frames to the client

'''

```
 from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse, StreamingHttpResponse
import cv2
import time
from django.views.decorators import gzip


class VideoCamera(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.video = cv2.VideoCapture('./streaming/video.mp4')

    def __del__(self):
        self.video.release()

    def get_frame(self):
        ret, image = self.video.read()
        ret, jpeg = cv2.imencode('.jpg', image)
        return jpeg.tobytes()


def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield(b'--frame\r\n'
              b'Content-Type: image/jpeg\r\n\r\n' + frame + b'\r\n\r\n')


@gzip.gzip_page
def index(request):
    try:
        return StreamingHttpResponse(gen(VideoCamera()), content_type="multipart/x-mixed-replace;boundary=frame")
    except HttpResponseServerError as e:
        print("aborted")
```

but i dont know how to handle the audio and data and the synchronization . i want to know what technology i have to use and if there any tutorial or ideas about it. i really don't know what to read and how to start (i'm using django).

Answer (score -1):

Follow for more details :

Github : https://github.com/JRodrigoF/AVrecordeR

```
class AudioRecorder():


    # Audio class based on pyAudio and Wave
    def __init__(self):

        self.open = True
        self.rate = 44100
        self.frames_per_buffer = 1024
        self.channels = 2
        self.format = pyaudio.paInt16
        self.audio_filename = "temp_audio.wav"
        self.audio = pyaudio.PyAudio()
        self.stream = self.audio.open(format=self.format,
                                      channels=self.channels,
                                      rate=self.rate,
                                      input=True,
                                      frames_per_buffer = self.frames_per_buffer)
        self.audio_frames = []


    # Audio starts being recorded
    def record(self):

        self.stream.start_stream()
        while(self.open == True):
            data = self.stream.read(self.frames_per_buffer) 
            self.audio_frames.append(data)
            if self.open==False:
                break


    # Finishes the audio recording therefore the thread too    
    def stop(self):

        if self.open==True:
            self.open = False
            self.stream.stop_stream()
            self.stream.close()
            self.audio.terminate()

            waveFile = wave.open(self.audio_filename, 'wb')
            waveFile.setnchannels(self.channels)
            waveFile.setsampwidth(self.audio.get_sample_size(self.format))
            waveFile.setframerate(self.rate)
            waveFile.writeframes(b''.join(self.audio_frames))
            waveFile.close()

        pass

    # Launches the audio recording function using a thread
    def start(self):
        audio_thread = threading.Thread(target=self.record)
        audio_thread.start()
```

**Actully I don't have much idea with open cv2. But I think we cannot record video with audio simultaneously. You have to capture audio and video in thread.**